# Rational varieties over finite fields admit an open set isomorphic to an affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, etale-covers

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303382.pdf) paper roughly claims that given a projective variety $X$ over a finite field, there is a finite map $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ such that if $H$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $U=\mathbb{A}^n$ is the complement of $H$, then the induced map $f:f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is étale.

So let us consider that $X$ is a rational smooth projective variety. Since $f:f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is étale and $X$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ have isomorphic function fields then it implies that $f:f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is an isomorphism. So this implies that there is actually an affine $f^{-1}(U)$ in $X$ which is $\mathbb{A}^n$.

I am not sure whether I'm making any mistakes or not, but this seems a little bit odd.

> **Question.** Is there any way to understand the complement of
> $f^{-1}(U)$? Like whether it is a smooth variety or not?

Comment: You are indeed making a mistake. That $k(X)$ and $k(\mathbb{P}^n)$ are isomorphic doesn't say that $f^*:k(\mathbb{P}^n)\rightarrow k(X)$ is an isomorphism.